# Migration configuration

Tags: migrations, 8

I'm setting up a migration from an URL with JSON on it.

Got the first level values without any issues. Currently I'm stuck at nested arrays which resemble something like this:

```
{   "content": [
    {
      "id": 148,
      "hardwares": [
        {
          "hwId": 16,
          "products": [
            {
              "pid": 2097,
              "productName": "ProductName1",
            },
            {
              "pid": 2100,
              "productName": "ProductName2",
            },
            {
              "pid": 2103,
              "productName": "ProductName3",
            },
            {
              "pid": 2094,
              "productName": "ProductName4",
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
   ], 
}
```

I have a custom content entity with a text field called Product Names, the field is a multi-value field. I've been trying to get the `productName` values and populate the field. Basically this JSON here would create one entity, and then get the value by this hierarchy:

`hardwares->products->productName`

I can't seem to grasp the usage of the sub_process plugin and I would really appreciate any hints or any working examples.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

I defined a field entry in the source:

```
  name: hardwares
  label: 'Hardwares'
  selector: hardwares
```

In my process:

```
_products:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: hardwares
    process:
      products:
        plugin: sub_process
        source: products
        process:
          productName: productName
field_products:
    plugin: flatten
    source: '@_products'
_hwIds:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: hardwares
    process:
      hwId: hwId
field_hardware_ids:
    plugin: flatten
    source: '@_hwIds'
```

In order to get to the 2nd level of my data array, I needed to nest the sub_process plugin. I flatten the result afterwards in order to get a numerically indexed array which resembles the multiple value field structure.